# I used Dask to read my 7GB CSV but now there is an error

Tags: python, dask

The error says "NotImplementedError: dd.DataFrame.apply only supports axis=1 Try: df.apply(func, axis=1)"

Here is my line of code:

```
# Read the CSV file in using dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('CICIDSs.csv')

features = df.dtypes[df.dtypes !='object'].index
df[features] = df[features].apply(
    lambda x: (x-x.mean())/ (x.std()))
#fill empty values by 0
df_pre = df.fillna(0)
print('===== Data Preprocessing =====')
print(df_pre)
```

I tried using the suggested code but it outputs an error where it says that `func is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
df[features] = df[features].apply(
    lambda x: (x-x.mean())/ (x.std()))
```

Did you try:

```py
df[features] = df[features].apply(
    lambda x: (x-x.mean())/ (x.std()),
    axis=1)
```